# Iphone6 or Ios8 safari images are repeating randomly issue

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ios8

i developed a new theme for magento store , everything is working fine except a new bug have occured , when the site is opened in iphone6 or iphone6 plus it shows repetitive images which are not even set as background images. The css properties they are inheriting are from bootstrap 2.
I have attached the img for reference moreover can't copy the whole lot of 8000 line off css here so it would be great if somebody help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In dev tools, iPhone shows the right file name for the background, but its not the actual file at all.  So the CSS is just fine, for whatever reason, iOS is sticking a random image in there and calling it by that file name instead of the actual image that is called that.  Super strange:
[iPhone 6 CSS Background Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDj4V.png)